# Need alternate SQL

Tags: sql, h2

I am currently working with an H2 database and I have written the following SQL, however the H2 database engine does not support the `NOT IN` being performed on a multiple column sub-query.

```
DELETE FROM AllowedParam_map
WHERE (AllowedParam_map.famid,AllowedParam_map.paramid) NOT IN (
SELECT famid,paramid 
FROM macros
LEFT JOIN macrodata 
ON macros.id != macrodata.macroid 
ORDER BY famid)
```

Essentially I want to remove rows from `allowedparam_map` wherever it has the same combination of `famid` and `paramid` as the sub-query

**Edit:** To clarify, the sub-query is specifically trying to find `famid/paramid` combinations that are NOT present in `macrodata`, in an effort to weed out the `allowedparam_map`, hence the `ON macros.id != macrodata.macroid`. I'm also terrible at SQL so this might be completely the wrong way to do it.

**Edit 2:** Here is some more info about the pertinent schema:

```
Macros
|  ID  | NAME  |  FAMID  |
|  0   |  foo  |    1    |
|  1   |  bar  |    1    |
|  2   |  baz  |    1    |

MacroData
|  ID  | MACROID  |  PARAMID  |  VALUE  |
|  0   |     0    |     1     |  1024   |
|  1   |     0    |     2     |  200    |
|  2   |     0    |     3     |  89.85  |

AllowedParam_Map
|  ID  |  FAMID  |  PARAMID  |
|  0   |    1    |     1     |
|  1   |    1    |     2     |
|  2   |    1    |     3     |
|  3   |    1    |     4     |
```

The parameters are allowed on a per-family basis. Notice how the `allowedParam_map` table contains an entry for `famid=1` and `paramid=4`, even though macro 0, aka "foo", does not have an entry for `paramid=4`. If we expand this, there might be another `famid=1` macro that has `paramid=4`, but we cant be sure. I want to cull from the `allowedParam_map` table any unused parameters, based on the data in the `macrodata` table.

Comment: What tables do `famid` and `paramid` reside in?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner `famid` and `paramid` reside in the `macros` table

Comment: As to your edit: "famid/paramid combinations that are NOT present in macrodata"? If the columns reside in the macros table, how can they be present or not present in the macrodata table? You may want to show what columns your tables actually contain. If you even give some sample data and expected results, that would be a great help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake when I wrote the comment before; the macros table does not have a `paramid`, column, hence my join with macrodata, which does have a `paramid`. I'll work on some additional info about the pertinent tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IN` and `NOT IN` can always be replaced with `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`.

Some points first:

- You are using an `ORDER BY` in your subquery, which is of course superfluous.
- You are outer-joining a table, which should have no effect when asking for existence. So either you need to look up a field in the outer-joined table, then inner-join it or you don't, then remove it from the query. (It's queer to join every non-related record (`macros.id != macrodata.macroid`) anyway.

<strike>You say in the comments section that both `famid` and `paramid` reside in table `macros`, so you can remove the outer join to `macrodata` from your query. You get:</strike>

As you say now that `famid` is in table `macros` and `paramid` is in table `macrodata` and you want to look up pairs that exist in `AllowedParam_map`, but not in the aformentioned tables, you seem to be looking for a simple inner join.

```
DELETE FROM AllowedParam_map
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM macros m
  JOIN macrodata md ON md.macroid = m.id
  WHERE m.famid = AllowedParam_map.famid
  AND md.paramid = AllowedParam_map.paramid
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not exists` instead:

```
DELETE FROM AllowedParam_map m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM macros LEFT JOIN
                       macrodata 
                       ON macros.id <> macrodata.macroid  -- I strongly suspect this should be =
                   WHERE m.famid = ?.famid and m.paramid = ?.paramid  -- add the appropriate table aliases
                  );
```

Notes:

- I strongly suspect the `<>` should be `=`.  `<>` does not make sense in this context.
- Replace the `?` with the appropriate table alias.
- `NOT EXISTS` is better than `NOT IN` anyway.  It does what you expect if one of the value is `NULL`.

Comment: For some reason, my original query would not work at all with `NOT EXISTS`, I just get a syntax error, yet changing back to `NOT IN` just complains about the multiple column sub-query.

Comment: @bss36504 . . . Did you replace the `?` with the appropriate table names?